# Error during WebSocket handshake Unexpected response code 400

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setting up a node js cloud server and I am using io sockets. When I do (in front):

```
const socket = io('wss://********.fr', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

I have this error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://********.fr/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

My site is in https and on my local machine I did not have this error.

I can't find a solution, have you got an idea ?

Théo

Comment: Have you tried setting your ``Socket.IO`` server to only use websockets?

Comment: yes I tried but it doesn't change anything